# Monitor asynchronous logger queue size in Log4j

Tags: log4j

Log4j asynchronous logger documentation states that there are some system properties that can be configured to control the log enqueue behavior once the queue gets full (e.g. block the thread or discard the message).

It seems reasonable that application owners would want to monitor the size of the queue before adjusting the buffer size. I wasn't able to find any documentation on this, so wondering if anyone knows if it's possible out of the box/without implementing a custom async logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I could find on my own after reading Log4j code, is to extend `DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy` with custom implementation and override the [getHandle](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy.java#L49) method.